# How to login with google using socialite in laravel 5.8 with different types of users

Tags: laravel, google-signin

I want to login with google socialite for two types of user.

1- Company Users.

2- Individuals users

In database users table i add a field sign_up_as if 1 then company users if 2 then individuals. so how i paas 1 and 2 value to signin with google link.

In the login view i add this code

```html
<li>
    <a href="{{ url('/redirect') }}"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
</li>
```

**Controller**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialite;
use App\Services\SocialGoogleAccountService;
use  Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;

class SocialAuthGoogleController extends Controller
{

    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function callback(SocialGoogleAccountService $service)
    {

        $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('google')->user());
        auth()->login($user);
        return redirect()->to('/home');
    }
}
```

**createOrGetUser function**

```php
public function createOrGetUser(ProviderUser $providerUser)
{
    // dd('now here');
    $account = SocialGoogleAccount::whereProvider('google')
        ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
        ->first();
    // dd($account);
    if ($account) {
        return $account->user;
    } else {
        $account = new SocialGoogleAccount([
            'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
            'provider' => 'google'
        ]);
        $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();
        if (!$user) {

            $user = User::create([
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                'password' => md5(rand(1, 10000)),
                'sign_up_as' => 2, // currently sign_up-as static
            ]);
        }
        $account->user()->associate($user);
        $account->save();
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution myself rather then passing values simple set the values in the session and get in the controller then save in the database like.

```
@php
  session(['sign_up_as' => '2']);
@endphp
```

and in the controller

```
$sign_up_as = session('sign_up_as');
```